# How to rename all file names under a folder to add modified date as prefix in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a folder **C:\Documents**

I have over **100** files under the folder.

```
file1.docx 
blah.docx
.
.
```

I would like to rename all files as below where modified_date is from the `LastWriteTime` timestamp on the file:

**A_{modified_date}_filename**  note that that must be **ddMMyyyy** format.

Example output:

```
A_01012015_file1.docx
A_20122014_blah.docx
```

I can write a simple console application to achieve this. But Just wondering if there is an existing tool built-in or by using Powershell?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean include the last write date in the file name like so:

```
Get-ChildItem | 
  Rename-Item -NewName {'A_' + $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('ddMMyyyy') + $_.name}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using @Dave answer.

I have figured out how to add any prefix at the end of each individual file as well.

```
Get-ChildItem | 
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName+'_'+$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('ddMMyyyy')+$_.Extension}
```

Note that BaseName is supported in PS v2 and above.

I hope it helps someone else out there.

BaseName is supported in PS v2 and above.

Answer (score 1):

`cmd /c for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/. " %a in ('date/T') do forfiles /p <PATH> /m *.xlsx /c "cmd /c ren @file %c%b%a_@file"`

Comment: Works also great when started e.g. from a macro in Access

Comment: OP asks for powershell. Now I think powershell will eat this but your answer is not in the spirit of the question. Maybe spend a few words on that by making an [edit].